# What is the CSS to change the width of sidebar?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I want to change the width of the sidebar on the right. There is too much space to the right and it is too close to the main information/images on the left/center.

I have looked through all the answers on here and tried out all the css advice. They produce no movement or change whatsoever.

Link to image of site page:

https://ibb.co/R2Cfvvv

Comment: What is the css/html for your page ?

Comment: Please go read [ask], [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it (and yes, I am aware you didn’t post a link to your site, you managed to give even _less_ useful information.)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to provide the css/html for my page on here?

Comment: @Christal At the least you need to provide the URL for the webpage

Comment: Sorry bout that.

https://kenkoroot.com/?product=fukujurai-tea-loose-leaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main content width:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-8, .tt_event_page_left, .woocommerce .woocommerce-cart-form {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
} }
```

Your sidebar content width:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-4, .tt_event_page_right, .woocommerce .cart-collaterals {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
} }
```

So adjust the values to your needs and if you want to add padding to the sidebar, add `padding-left` property.
Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-4, .tt_event_page_right, .woocommerce .cart-collaterals {
padding-left: 75px;
} }
```

Comment: @Christal Glad to help you! If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as "accepted" (check mark).